# What does "PSA" mean?

Tags: discussion

A number of questions have "PSA: " in the title, like it's being used as a faux-tag. But searching for it using the box in the upper-right just gives 3 such questions (why only 3?) And not any explaination.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've removed "PSA" from the title of [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions), as that's the one I end up linking to for new users very frequently.

Answer (score 4):

It means "public service announcement" and has been used in meta posts by some users to indicate a "question" that is intended to be informative rather than actually be a question.